# How to change part of HTML src elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

I want to change the word of the large crop link for word with javascript. The url changes every update, but the suffix "large" continues, but I wanna change every update to "crop". I am a beginner, I'm sorry for this boring question

```
<img id="cover" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000088629087-uoefpq-large.jpg">
```

to

```
<img id="cover" src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000088629087-uoefpq-crop.jpg">
```

Comment: Don't know why people dislike your answer, I find it quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var elt = document.getElementById("cover");
elt.src = elt.src.replace("large", "crop");
```

Note that this may not work as you expect if the "crop" is in the url more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.getElementById` to get the `cover` element

```
var src = document.getElemtnById('cover').src;
```

Modify the `src` variable

```
src = src.replace('large', 'crop');
```

Update the `src` attribute

```
document.getElemtnById('cover').src = src;
```